# rollmean length of timeseries

Tags: r, time-series, mean, moving-average

I have a time series of regular 15 minute data intervals and I want to take a rolling average of the data for every 2 hours, hence the width of the rollmean interval would be 8. The only issue is that the length of the original time series that I put in is 35034, but the length of the data that I get as output is 35027. Is there a way that the length of the output is the same as the input and does have data in it at the end as well. i dont want to fill it with NA's at the end

```
interval <- 2 #2 hours
data <- data.frame(t=streamflowDateTime,flow=streamflow)
data2hr <- data
rollingWidth <- (interval*60)/15
library(zoo)
smoothedFlow <- rollmean(data2hr$flow,rollingWidth,align="center")
```

Comment: Use `runmean` from `caTools` which is much faster and has an `endrule` argument to do whatever you want with the endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely clear on how you want to do the filling but here are some ways:

**1)** Add the argument `fill = NA` to `rollmean` to add NA's to the ends.

**2)** If you want partial means at the ends then use this where `x` is your data, `width` is the number of points to take the mean of each time:

```
rollapply(x, width, mean, partial = TRUE)
```

(The points near the ends will be the mean of fewer than width points since,  of course, there just aren't that many near the ends.)

**3)** Assuming width is odd you could pad the input series with (width-1)/2 values (possibly NA depending on what you want) on each end.

**4)**  This keeps the original values near the ends:

```
out <- rollmean(x, width, fill = NA)
isNA <- is.na(out)
out[isNA] <- x[isNA]
```

**Note:** `align = "center"` is the default for both `rollmean` and `rollapply` so that can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want NA, you can use fill parameter for extending the data range with simple constant values:

With keyword "extend" rollmean will extend your input vector:

```
rollmean(x, k, align="center", fill = "extend")
```

or define a three component constant for left|at|right:

```
rollmean(x, k, align="center", fill = c(42, 69, 666))
```